# Nvim: Warning: Cannot find word list "cz.utf-8.spl" or "cz.ascii.spl"

Tags: vim, spell-checking, dictionary, nvim

When I turn on spell checking for Czech language, this happens:

```
:Sccz
No spell file for "cz" in utf-8
Download it?

Downloading cz.utf-8.spl...
:!curl 'http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/spell/cz.utf-8.spl' -L -o '/tmp/nvimfQsady/1.spl'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   309  100   309    0     0   1931      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1931
"/tmp/nvimfQsady/1.spl" 9L, 309C
Could not find it, trying cz.ascii.spl...
:!curl 'http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/spell/cz.ascii.spl' -L -o '/tmp/nvimfQsady/1.spl'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   309  100   309    0     0   1861      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1861
"/tmp/nvimfQsady/1.spl" 9L, 309C
Download failed
Warning: Cannot find word list "cz.utf-8.spl" or "cz.ascii.spl"
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: do those files exist on that server?

Comment: @jsotola I tried url in browser and they do not exist. But nvim try this url automaticly.

Comment: look at the other files and directories on that server ... it appears that `cz` is `cs` on this server .... research how to install custom spell check files in vim ... do the install manually